# Python Regex to extract content of src of an html tag?

Tags: python, regex

I tried something like this but failed. I don't know regex can anyone help me with this?

```
import re

html = """
<body>
<h1>dummy heading</h1>
<img src="/pic/earth.jpg" alt="planet" width="200">
<img src="/pic/redrose.jpg" alt="flower" width="200">
</body>
"""
x = re.search('^src=".*jpg$', html)
print(x)
```

I'm expecting output like this ['/pic/earth.jpg','/pic/redrose.jpg']

Comment: Better approach is to use HTML parser, such as `BeautifulSoup`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

Comment: Yeah, I know but I want this using Regex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not good at regEx. So my answer may not be best.

Try this.

```
x = re.findall(r'(?=src)src=\"(?P<src>[^\"]+)', html)
```

than you can see x like below.

```
['/pic/earth.jpg', '/pic/redrose.jpg']
```

RegEx explanation :

(?=src) : positive lookup --> only see those have **src** word

src=\"  : must include this specific word **src="**

(?P somthing) : this expression grouping somthing to name **src**

[^\"]+ : everything except " character

Answer (score 3):

Good first start, but you have several minor issues with your code:

- `^` and `$` refer to the start and end of the string

  - or end-of-line with re.MULTILINE flag enabled
- `.search()` returns `Null` or a `Match` object rather than the matched strings
- you probably want the `.findall()` method
- if you have backslashed in your regex (which you don't yet), then you may want to use raw `r"string"` strings for your regex code
- also think of all the possible permutations of what could be in your input data, such as HTML allowing both `'` and `"` for quotes, and that there could be a `src=` attribute in something that is not an image

Here are the docs:
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Try this as a regex:

```
image_urls = re.findall(r'<img[^<>]+src=["\']([^"\'<>]+\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g))["\']', html, re.I)
print(image_urls)
>>> ['/pic/earth.jpg', '/pic/redrose.jpg']
```

To break this down a little:

- `re.findall()` return a list of strings
- `<img` we are looking to start in an image tag
- `[^<>]+` 1 or more chars that don't open/close the html tag

  - there might not be a `src=""` tag in the current `<img>`
- `["\']` the HTML could use either type of quote
- `[^"\'<>]+` keep reading 1+ chars whilst the string and the tag are not closed
- `\.` literal dots need to be escaped, else they mean the "match anything" special char
- `(?:gif|png|jpe?g)` a range of possible file extensions, but don't create a capture bracket for them (which would return these in your array)
- `([^"\'<>]+\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g))` this is the capture bracket for what will actually get returned for each match
- `["\']` search for the closing quote to end the capture bracket
- `re.I` make the regex case insensitive